# Solving equations with conjugated complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to solve an equation and I could use some help.

Let's say the given equation is $$z\bar z+3\bar z+z=13-2i$$

Steps I take to solve the equation:

\begin{align*}
(x+iy)(x-iy)+3(x-iy)+x+yi&=13-2i \\
x^2+y^2+4x-2yi&=13-2i
\end{align*}
Now I separate imaginary part for real part
\begin{align*}
-2yi&=-2i \quad\text{and}\\
x^2+y^2+4x&=13
\end{align*}

So at this point I know that my complex number contains imaginery part $i$, and I need to find real part, but I have one equation and two more unknowns $y,x$.

Did I miss something?

Regards,
L.K.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. Was editing it right now, though Christoph was faster, thank you :)

Comment: Remember that, $$x+iy=a+ib\iff x=a\land y=b~,~x,y\in\Bbb{R}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When separating an equation like $a+bi=a'+b'i$ into real and imaginary parts, you can leave out the $i$ to get real equations $a=a'$, $b=b'$. In your case the equation for the imaginary part is $-2y=-2$ which yields $y=1$. Plug this into the equation for the real part and solve for $x$.

Comment: Thank you very much :) The answer I got is -6+i ; 2+i

Answer (score 2):

Saying that your imaginary part is $i$ is equivalent to saying that $y=1$.  This means you have only one unknown remaining.

Comment: Thanks for the response :)